# Warning in Play 2.0.4

Tags: scala, playframework, securesocial

When I compile my application with securesocial plugin it gives me this warning:

```
[info] Compiling 21 Scala sources and 8 Java sources to /home/mario/tegik-play/target/scala-2.9.1/classes...
[warn] /home/mario/tegik-play/app/controllers/TemplatesPlugin.scala:21: imported `Application' is permanently hidden by definition of object Application in package controllers
[warn] import play.api.{Logger, Plugin, Application}
[warn]        ^
[warn] one warning found
```

I'm new to scala, does anyone have a pointer for this?

Answer (score 0):

When using `Application`, the compiler will *choose* the one you got in your current package, `controllers`, instead of `play.api.Application`; which means that importing the latter is useless.

In other words: the definition of `controllers.Application` hides the definition of `play.api.Application`.

To silence that warning, don't import `play.api.Application`, and use it with its full name:

```
import play.api.{Logger, Plugin}

...

val foo = play.api.Application.bar
```